# jquery how to hide div on click a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('#banner').click(function show_stuff() {
var s = document.getElementById("dropdown_c");
s.style.height = "200px";
s.style.border = "1px solid #e9eaee";
});
```

when banner is clicked dropdown_c div is showed

how to hide dropdown_c when clicking banner again

here is my code only to show the div not to hide

i want to allow user to show/hide this div on clicking banner

Comment: Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: can u help me with the code

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: ^^ use the link provided by - undefined && MattDiamant. Code samples on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `Toggle()` recognizes the current state of the element (show / hide) and applies the opposite effect to the selected element.

**CODE:**

```
$('#banner').on('click', function(){

        $('dropdown_c').toggle();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#banner').click(function() {
      $("#dropdown_c").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to implement, all you have to do is use the method toggle() on the dropdown everytime banner is clicked. Also just a side note, you should stick to one naming / selecting convention just for more legible code! Hope this helps :)

```
$('#banner').click(function toggle_stuff() {
    $('#dropdown_c').toggle(); // you can also use slide or fade
});
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/DSTQw/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function(){

if($('.hide').is(':hidden')){
//alert('hiden');
$('.hide').slideDown('1000');
}
else{
$('.hide').slideUp('1000');
}   
});
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MdTFx/)